# How to hide InputField additional input box in unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, input-field

I use a `FiledInput` in android app and when I starting to put string in it a `softkeyboard` pops up and a box, I want to get rid of it.

Is it any way to do so using `Unity3d 4.6.2f1` ?

[image: text]

Comment: In html app you can use [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) element attributes, but not sure if that can help your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [InputField.shouldHideMobileInput](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-shouldHideMobileInput.html) for that.

Comment: This works great and also there is a "Hide Mobile Input" option in Editor that do the trick.

Comment: "hide Mobile Input" as well as "InputField.shouldHideMobileInput" didn't work me.

Comment: According to information here from Unity staff posted om March 15: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/hidden-mobile-input.310709/ :
                      
- [Dev] But why did Hide Mobile Input worked before? Like you could still type in text to Input Field without the text box, ... 
                     
[Unity Guy] ... ever since we added support for hidden input field, it has been causing more harm than good :-(               
                   
[Another Unity Guy] We have started working on that but nothing has been released yet. - yes, we are aware the current layout/style looks like @#$.

Comment: as for today this problem is still on, just keep waiting Unity staff will sort this out...

Comment: This isn't supported on Android: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html

Comment: "hide Mobile Input" is still not working... The annoying thing is that all text is marked when clicked and gets overwritten by typing.

Comment: 2 years and 3 months later... still doesn't work. Is there really no solution to this?