# Unity 4.6 InputField doesn't work stable with android

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine, touch

So I have an issue with the fairly new Unity 4.6 UI system. 
I have a multiplattform project and everything works fine (pc/ ios) but my input fields for the user to log in sometimes don't open the Touchkeyboard, or it is not possible to focus them. 
I guess I have to open the keyboard manually, focus the inputfield and do the navigation myself, but there is not a lot of documentation about it...
so my questions:

1. How do I hide the mobile input field (the one above the keyboard) via Script on run time?
2. How can I keep the keyboard always open, but still use the submit-event of the keyboard?
3. Any other cool ideas which could fix my issue?

I am running on my test device android 4.1.2,  4.2.2 and 4.4.2 and I can recreate that problem on all of those, even though 4.4.2 seems to be the worse.

Thank you very much my brave Unity UI warriors!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using latest unity version, they had a few bugs related to InputField in 4.6. If that doesn't help, you should try [patch releases](http://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases).

[How to hide InputField additional input box in unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671213/how-to-hide-inputfield-additional-input-box-in-unity3d)

Comment: We are using the latest Unity 4 version 4.6.4 and Unity 5 is not an Option... But the patch releases are looking promising, thank you :) I totally forgot about them. o.O

Comment: Well Patch releases are not an option either, cause they do not allow webbuilds etc... any other ideas?

Comment: I would suggest you to create an empty scene with InputField and see if it works, maybe your problem appears only with certain hierarchy, nested masks or something like that.

Comment: Found a temporary fix, do not hide the mobile input. It is not exactly what i was looking for but at least users can log in.