# Unity Input fields

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried using unity's build-in input fields, but I don't like 2 things:

1) The bar with "OK" cannot be removed. (I tried setting hide mobile input, but it does not work)[image]

2) No matters where I tap I'm always starting editing text in front or like shown on the picture above.

I'm quite sure that I'm doing something wrong with first one (it should be working)
and the 2nd can be connected with 1st. Any ideas would be helpful. (Text mesh pro seems to behave like build-in)

Comment: Is that the default keyboard of yours? Is your code on opening the keyboard like this ? `TouchScreenKeyboard.Open("", TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default, false, false, true, true);`

Comment: @TheGinxx009 it's default unity input field, I'm not opening keyboard via my own script.
Is it possible to use different method of opening keyboard that overrides default unity input field?

Comment: @TheGinxx009 I tested the function you provided and it's working in the same way (with "OK" bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) The bar with "OK" cannot be removed. (I tried setting hide mobile input, but it does not work)

According to this post: [How to hide InputField additional input box in unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671213/how-to-hide-inputfield-additional-input-box-in-unity3d)

Which leads to this link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html

Android is not supported for the boolean value that hides the keyboard.

> Hide Mobile Input (iOS only)

Comment: I missed the iOS only. Is there any way of making this work in the way I described? I'm pretty sure that it's possible somehow. Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: One alternative would be to make your own custom keyboard using Unity's UI buttons. It's a bit troublesome but that way you have complete freedom of what you want to be presented.